# How to Edit Random Element based on Another Random Element on a Page with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I don't know if there's such an option in jquery, i've tried "find,contains,has" selectors, but couldn't accomplish what i need.

I have a software code I can't access, so to change layout I can only fiddle with CSS and jQuery.

Here's sample code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Filter by Day</label>
    <div>
        <label for="chkDayWednesday" class="cpv-checkbox font-weight-normal">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkDayWednesday" id="chkDayWednesday" checked="checked">
            <i></i>
            Wednesday
        </label>
        <br>
        <div style="margin-top: -6px; margin-bottom: -18px;">
            <label for="chkDayThursday" class="cpv-checkbox font-weight-normal">
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkDayThursday" id="chkDayThursday" checked="checked">
                <i></i>
                Thursday
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to add style to that div below:

```
<div style="margin-top: -6px; margin-bottom: -18px;">
```

Problem is that on the page, there are multiple classes like: .form-group.
I can only use one unique element, which is either:

```
id="chkDayWednesday"
```

or

```
id="chkDayThursday"
```

so question is, how based on these unique elements on the page, i can go up or down to the div with negative margins and edit it?

I tried something like this:

```
$("label:contains('Thursday')").css({"background-color": "yellow"});
```

but it only selects the label itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try .closest() ? that finds the closest parent element.
Example:

```
$("label:contains('Thursday')").closest("div").css("background", "yellow");
```

Comment: wow, thanx so much, so simple and easy. I tried it, but must have messed up somewhere. Thanx again

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of the question you want to add `background-color:yellow` to the `div` with child having id `chkDayThursday`, so since we do not have a proper CSS method to do this, we can go with JQuery which is a well known one. just find the element with id `chkDayThursday` then find the parent `div` as shown in snippet and style it!

Please let me know if I have missed anything, since my undestanding is a bit hazy!

```js
$('#chkDayThursday').parent().parent().css({"background-color": "yellow"})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Filter by Day</label>
    <div>
        <label for="chkDayWednesday" class="cpv-checkbox font-weight-normal">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkDayWednesday" id="chkDayWednesday" checked="checked">
        <i></i>
            Wednesday
        </label>
        <br>
        <div style="margin-top: -6px; margin-bottom: -18px;">
            <label for="chkDayThursday" class="cpv-checkbox font-weight-normal">
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkDayThursday" id="chkDayThursday" checked="checked">
                <i></i>
                Thursday
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You very much, this works very well also. I just didn't know the proper syntax for it, spent prob. 4+ hours today trying to figure it out. Appreciate it!!